# is it correct to use 'often a times'?

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Does the phrase "often a times" exist? If so, what is the correct way to use it?

Would the following sentence be correct?

> I have seen him loafing about in the streets **often a times**.

Comment: You probably mean *oftentimes*. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/oftentimes. 'Often a times' is not a used expression.

Comment: Nope. I have a vivid recollection of having read the phrase **often a times** in a few books.

Comment: It is not present in Google. Books: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=often+a+times+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=. Might be a slang expression or simply a typo.

Comment: There's *"oftentimes"* (common) and *"often a time"* (rarer). Maybe you're conflating the two.

Answer (score 1):

The Ngram viewer is ignorant of "often a times," but it finds "often at times," currently out-written 100 to 1 by "oftentimes."  From [Young Children at School in in the Inner City](https://books.google.com/books?id=yiGffag02Z8C&pg=PA65&dq=%22often%20at%20times%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMI0OSttLDQxwIVzHg-Ch3WIgbv#v=onepage&q=%22often%20at%20times%22&f=false) by Barbara Tizard:

> It seems likely, too, that disruptive behaviour occurred more **often at
>   times** not observed,....

But the google finds the phrase about 175K times in [websites](http://www.collegefootballtopten.com/sbobet.html) saying things like

> Sports betting **often a times** has been referred to as gambling where a
>   bet is made in prediction of the outcome of a particular game.

The phrase "often at times" gets only 350K hits.  (By way of contrast, "oftentimes" gets 11.7M.)  I'm tempted to say that "often a times" is merely a phonetic transcription of "often at times," when the final "t" in "a**t**" gets consumed by the initial "t" in "**t**imes."

Comment: As far as I can tell, "oftentimes" (or "ofttimes") can almost always be replaced by "often", and probably should be. By contrast I would suggest that "often at times" is best used as part of a longer phrase such as "They always went to church at least once a week, more often at times" or "She reported from many countries, often at times of conflict".